How do I predict electrical mean free path in nanostructures
How does one roughly predict the mean free path for electrical conduction in a nanostructure at different temperatures and under different electrical conditions such as different voltages and amperages based on the composition and dimensions of the structure?
For instance in carbon single and multilayer nanotubes vs graphene ribbons vs silicon nanowires, and all of different sizes.
In other words how do I predict the average range of electrical ballistic conduction in a described structure under different power and temperature conditions?
I am trying to model out these structures and their electrical properties as I hope to in turn model out some simple circuits using them and see how they might behave.
I am hoping there is a convenient formula or combined set of formulas I can use.

Perhaps better on Physics?

My luck with the Physics section for help modeling things like electrical components and looking at anything even remotely less concrete than normal  such as how to figure out what happens if factor x is used in y configuration with factor z, has historically been poor. I figured that as I am trying to model out a type of microelectronic part for modeling out circuits using it, that the Engineering section would be a good fit. Granted I have also asked the Physics section though I am not expecting any good results from there. My querying method is not well received by most highbrows.
